# MapView annotations: finding coordinates

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have many MKMapViews, and each of them has an annotation. I am trying to retrieve the coordinates of each in this way:

```
for (MKMapView *map in MapViewArray)
{
    // add textfield contents to array



    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", map.annotations];

    [latitudes addObject: latitude];
}
```

I was looking for the right code instead of this:

```
map.annotations
```

I want to find the latitude here..

How can I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each map annotation is an object, so you'll have to get the coordinate value from the annotation instead. The annotations are stored in `map.annotations`, which is an array. If you only have one annotation per map, you can use this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [[map.annotations lastObject] coordinate];
NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", coordinate.latitude];
```

If you have multiple annotations, you'll obviously have to iterate through each one individually, then get the location data.

Comment: It gives this error: property coordinate not found on object of type id